# limitations of non linear multivariant equation solvers in matlab

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, equation

I have a system of non-linear multivariate equations. I am only interested in the roots of the system in an interval of each variable.

For example,

```
F = @(x,y,z) [...
    sin((x*y)/100 + (y*z)/5)/10 + sin((y*z)/10)/10 + (y*cos((y*z)/10)*(x/10 + z))/100 + (y*cos((x*y)/100 + (y*z)/5)*(x/5 + z))/50 = 0  
    (z*cos((y*z)/10)*(x/10 + z))/100 + (cos((x*y)/100 + (y*z)/5)*(x/5 + z)*(x/100 + z/5))/10 = 0
    sin((x*y)/100 + (y*z)/5)/50 + sin((y*z)/10)/100 + (y*cos((x*y)/100 + (y*z)/5)*(x/5 + z))/1000 = 0   
];
```

and I am only interested in the interval of `x` in `[0 10]` and `y` in `[-10 10]` and `z` in `[-5, 10]`.

My question is:

1. is there any method that can find 'all' the roots in these interval?
2. is there any solution that can tell me only number of roots in these intervals ?
3. If there is no general solution for question 1 and 2 (which I think there is not), then under what condition I can find all the roots (e.x. linear equations or polynomial are clearly solvable, but I want something more general such as Trigonometric equations).

Comment: please post a piece of code if you have tried something. Then it will be easy to help you.

Comment: If you have the optimization toolbox, take a look at [this MATLAB documentation page](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/nonlinear-systems-with-constraints.html). I suggest you try the `lsqnonlin` approach. Come back here if you have problems.